# Unity TMPro element doesn't display whole text

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with a Save/Load system in my project that I can't understand why is happening.

I'm saving currently displayed dialogue to a file and then during loading I pass it to a TMPro element to display it. The text is passed correctly (I think), because it shows up in the inspector as shown on the screenshot, but it doesn't get printed out in the game scene.

[Unity Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN3zH.jpg)

Comment: it looks like it goes behind something

Comment: what happens if you try with another font?

Comment: Pretty much nothing. Although it does look like it's just covered up by something. It's not being covered up by other objects though. Does TMPro have any max visible character variable or something like that?

Edit: It does

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much the stupidest error I've made but turns out that I've changed the maxVisibleCharacters variable somewhere in the code and didn't realise it.